# adding CustomerSalesTeam in customer in netsuite PHPToolkit

Tags: oracle, magento, netsuite

When I try to add CustomerSalesTeam in Customer in netsuite via my PHP code. it gives me a error

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soapenv:Server.userException] org.xml.sax.SAXException: salesTeam on {urn:relationships_2013_1.lists.webservices.netsuite.com}CustomerSalesTeamList must be of type {urn:relationships_2013_1.lists.webservices.netsuite.com}CustomerSalesTeam in C:\wamp\www\ns\PHPToolkit\NSPHPClient.php:287 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\ns\PHPToolkit\NSPHPClient.php(287): SoapClient->__soapCall('add', Array, NULL, Array) #1 C:\wamp\www\ns\PHPToolkit\NetSuiteService.php(118604): NSPHPClient->makeSoapCall('add', Object(AddRequest)) #2 C:\wamp\www\ns\samples\add_customer.php(38): NetSuiteService->add(Object(AddRequest)) #3 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\ns\PHPToolkit\NSPHPClient.php on line 287

```
And my Customer adding Code is :

    require_once '../PHPToolkit/NetSuiteService.php';

$service = new NetSuiteService();

$customer = new Customer();
$customer->lastName = "sale";
$customer->firstName = "rep";
$customer->companyName = "sale rep testing";
$customer->phone = "123456789";

$cst=new CustomerSalesTeam();
//$c=new CustomerSalesTeam();
//$em=new RecordRef();
//$em->internalId='1333083';
//$cst->employee=$em;
$cst->employee->internalId="1372";
$cst->salesRole->internalId="1";
$cst->isPrimary=true;
$cst->contribution=10.4;


$cstl=new CustomerSalesTeamList();
$cstl->replaceAll=true;
//$cstl->salesTeam[]=$cst;
$cstl->salesTeam =array($cst);
//$cstl->salesTeam=$cst;
$customer->salesTeamList=$cstl;

//$salesRep=new RecordRef();
//$salesRep->internalId='2792';
//$customer->salesRep=$salesRep;
$request = new AddRequest();
$request->record = $customer;

//$service->update($arg)
$addResponse = $service->add($request);

if (!$addResponse->writeResponse->status->isSuccess) {
    echo "ADD ERROR";
    print_r($addResponse->writeResponse);
} else {
    echo "ADD SUCCESS, id " . $addResponse->writeResponse->baseRef->internalId;
}
```

Comment: I am using PHPToolkit.

Answer (score 0):

you should have added the internal id of the Sales Team that you have created in Setup > Sales > Sales Teams and not the member of the sales team.

i am not good in PHP but i assume this will work.

```
$cst=new CustomerSalesTeam();
$cst->salesTeamList->internalId= idofyoursalesteam;
```

Comment: But "salesTeamList" not the CustomerSalesTeam property. it is CustomerSalesTeamList property. how can is use with CustomerSalesTeam.

Comment: are you assigning a sales team to a customer?

Comment: Yes i want to assign sales team

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
$cst=new CustomerSalesTeam();
```

with

```
$cst=new CustomerSalesTeam_relationships();
```